# open video full sceen in mobile size (below 768px)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

Hi i am using html5lightbox to play video.i need the solution  when i resize my window to 767px the video play full screen without the lightbox.

**mycode**

```
<a title="Big Buck Bunny Copyright Blender Foundation" data-group="set1" class="html5lightbox" data-thumbnail="images/Big_Buck_Bunny_1_96.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4?rel=0"><img src="images/Big_Buck_Bunny_1_96.jpg"></a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="html5lightbox/html5lightbox.js"></script>
```

also suggest me if any other plugin's like i mentioned. i'm just blank. please help me.